# What options are available to hide a TV in the bedroom?

Tags: furniture, bedroom

I'm having a wardrobe fitted in the master bedroom of our house, and I'm in a bit of a conundrum as to where I'm going to put the TV.  The room itself isn't big, when the wardrobe's fitted it will look something like this:

[image: Master bedroom]

The wardrobe isn't going to be big enough to fit the TV inside *as well as* having enough room for the storage we need.  The TV size is 40", we watch a lot of TV in the bedroom and, while I wouldn't mind if I had to  reduce the size a little (perhaps as low as 32"), I'd prefer not to have the extra expense.

We've looked over several solutions but unable to find anything suitable.

- **Wall-mounted, swivel TV bracket**
  We feel this would look untidy as we have several boxes connecting (Sky box, blu-ray) with wires.  A wireless HD solution would fix this too, but again, it's even more expense.
- **Ceiling mounted TV lift**
  This is the dream solution, but those things are ridiculously expensive.
- **Ottoman with TV lift**
  Slightly cheaper than the ceiling mount idea, but taking extra space at the end of the bed and shrinking the available floor space.
- **Bed with TV lift at the foot**
  We have a really nice bed and we're reluctant to change it.  Of course, this is also an expensive option.

I had an idea of my own, but I'm not sure how viable it is.  I wondered if there were any mounts which would allow the TV to lift up into a horizontal position and slide backwards into the wardrobe, laying flat on a shelf above the hanging rails.  This would mean we would have to live without sliding doors, but it seems like a neat solution to the problem.  I've seen [this bracket](http://www.that-leisure-company.co.uk/nexus-lcd005-flipdownslide-out-under-cabinet-lcd-tv-moun-p496137.html), but it's only for small TVs.

[image]

Does anyone have any better ideas, or a way to implement my own idea?

**EDIT**

The dimensions of the nook, which will effectively be the external space of the wardrobe, are about W74" x D36" x H95".

Comment: you could put it *under* the bed: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWFAEghVfEw

Comment: @BMitch: the fact that I can't even find a price for that says a lot :-) Does look cool, though.

Comment: How about a ceiling mounted TV projector with the closet doors as the screen.

Comment: What is above the room? Could you have the tv drop down through the ceiling?

Comment: Your solution might not work with a larger TV, since you'd have to pull the tv out fairly far from the wardrobe to be able to fold it up/down.

Comment: How high is the ceiling?  Is there any space above the wardrobe? How deep is the wardrobe?

Comment: @Tester101: yes, that would pretty much be my ideal solution but the kits are priced into the thousands (of pounds).  The loft is above, so it would be perfect.

Comment: @Craig: I added dimensions to the question.  Because of the window (and window ledge), the wardrobe can't be as deep as I would have liked it.  The wardrobe will go from ceiling to floor and wall to wall.

Comment: @NiallC: that's another option I could take into consideration, I guess.  It would have to be onto a screen, though, because the doors will be dark wood/red glass.

Comment: I like the drop down projector screen idea!  It's a bigger TV and you can usually find the motorized drop down screens for not too much.

Comment: Custom cabinet at the foot of the bed with the TV lift inside it?  Mounted on the ceiling flat against the ceiling so when you’re laying in bed you’re looking straight up at it?  Upgrade your closet doors to solid wood doors and hang it on the right side door of the bifold door that’s on the left so when the door swings out the TV doesn’t interfere with the companion door on the left of it ?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved exactly the same problem in my bedroom:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the projector hidden at all or just sticking down off the ceiling?

Comment: It's hanging from the ceiling. You can also get a motorized ones that hide in the ceiling when not used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why having several boxes is a problem for the swivel wall mount, but not for a ceiling/etc mount? Either way you have to have the boxes somewhere, and I assume you didn't intend for them to be hanging from the ceiling..

---

The wall mount is simple. You can use a mount like this:

[image: Monoprice wall mount]

---

Put all your other equipment in the wardrobe/closet. Get a couple long HDMI cables (or whatever you need) to connect to the TV.

Alternatively, you can also get wall-mount shelves for mounting equipment, if you don't mind seeing it sitting out (and of course, you can use any random shelf from anywhere, if you like):

[image: equipment mount]
<sub>(source: [monoprice.com](http://images2.monoprice.com/productmediumimages/57151.jpg))</sub>

---

You can use an IR Repeater so you're able to control the devices even if you can't see them.

[image: Smarthome IR repeater]

---

You can use some kind of cable wrap or wire raceway (eg Wiremold) to route the wires over (which looks WAY neater than just having a bundle of wires):

[image: velcro cable wrap]
[image: wiremold raceway]

Alternatively, if you're really adventurous, route the wires through the walls (and/or ceiling). Since you're on an exterior wall this would be a huge pain (due to vapour barrier and insulation), and personally, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: This might be the option we end up choosing, but still, I'd prefer not to have the TV on the wall.  Yes, I was going to put the boxes in the wardrobe and use an IR repeater all along anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I like the ceiling idea.  If you could find someone with some fab / welding skills it shouldn't be too much work to make one up.  You usually just need a flat piece of steel with some holes drilled through it for the back of the TV.  Then it just needs to be connected to either a pipe or square stick that is then welded to a plate on the ceiling (or goes through the ceiling).

It's probably way cheaper to go that route than it is to buy one of the commercial editions.

Comment: My dad has pretty good welding skills so I could ask him to help.  I just thought it must be so expensive for a reason.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's just because it hasn't become a commodity product yet.  If you do go that route please post a pic!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your TV should NOT be in your bedroom. Here are a couple reasons why:
[18 Good Reasons to Get the TV Out of Your Bedroom](https://www.becomingminimalist.com/18-darn-good-reasons-to-get-the-tv-out-of-the-bedroom/)
[Why a TV Does NOT Belong in the Bedroom](https://www.meetmindful.com/tv-does-not-belong-in-the-bedroom/)

Ok now with that out of the way, if you insist on the tv in the room, then there are a lot of ways. One person mentioned a projector, another mentioned a wall mount, both good options.

If it were me, I would not keep the bed in this configuration for this small room (without the TV my configuration below is even better).

Instead, I would flip the bed so there was more living space. Depending on where noise is coming from, put the bed on the opposite side. If noise comes from inside, choose the first with the headboard by the window. If noise comes from outside, then put the headboard on the other side away from the window; the benefit also of this second choice is there won't be any glare on the TV during the day.

Attach the TV to the side wall using a fully articulating wall mount. Move into place when you watch, and the might even be space to keep it out depending on the size of your bed and the size of your room. I based this on the to-size dimensions from your example picture. Likely, you might have more space. You also might be able to remove your footboard to save another few inches.

I would probably choose the second option unless there was noise coming from another person inside the apartment through the wall.

Option 1:

[image]

Option 2:

[image]

Hope this helps!

But please don't put the TV in your bedroom.